# Convert any string to an integer

Tags: sql, oracle, hash, oracle11gr2

Simply put, I'd like to be able to convert any string to an integer, preferably being able to restrict the size of the integer and ensure that the result is always identical. In other words is there a hashing function, supported by Oracle, that returns a numeric value and can that value have a maximum?

To provide some context if needed, I have two tables that have the following, simplified, format:

```
  Table 1                  Table 2

  id | sequence_number     id | sequence_number
  --------------------     -------------
  1  | 1                    1 | 2QD44561
  1  | 2                    1 | 6HH00244
  2  | 1                    2 | 5DH08133
  3  | 1                    3 | 7RD03098
  4  | 2                    4 | 8BF02466
```

The column `sequence_number` is `number(3)` in Table 1 and `varchar2(11)` in Table 2; it is part of the primary key in both tables.

The data is externally provided and cannot be changed; in Table 1 it is, I believe, created by a simple sequence but in Table 2 has a meaning. The data is made up but representative.

*Someone* has promised that we would output a `number(3)` field. While this is fine for the column in the first table, it causes problems for the second.

I would like to be able to both convert `sequence_number` to an integer (easy), that is less than 1000 (harder) *and* if at all possible is constant (seemingly impossible). This means that I would like `'2QD44561'` to *always* return `586`. It does not matter, much, if two strings return the same number.

Simply converting to an integer I can use `utl_raw.cast_to_number()`:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_number((utl_raw.cast_to_raw('2QD44561'))) from dual;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER((UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('2QD44561')))
---------------------------------------------------------
                                               -2.033E+25
```

But as you can see this isn't less than 1000

I've also been playing around with `dbms_crypto` and `utl_encode` to see if I could come up with something but I've not managed to get a small integer. Is there a way?

Comment: Can you just use the right three digits of the sequence number?

Comment: hmmm, I could do... it's definitely an idea to consider; too simple so I didn't think of that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [`ora_hash`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions124.htm)?

```
select ora_hash(sequence_number, 999) from table_2;
```

... will produce a maximum of 3 digits. You could also seed it with the `id` I suppose, but not sure that adds much with so few values, and I'm not sure you'd want that anyway.

Comment: Just found that :-), it seems to provide less clashes than the last 3 digits. Thanks! There's no need to seed it with the ID, unless that provided less clashes but it doesn't seem like it does.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about using a hash function. There are lots of solutions out there - sha1 is very common.

But just FYI, when you say "restrict the size of the integer" understand that you will then be mapping an infinite set of strings or numbers onto a limited set of values. So while your strings will always map to the same value when they are the same, they will not be the only string to map to that value

Comment: I don't understand what this adds. My question includes everything you've written apart from mentioning sha1 by name, which doesn't produce a number...